# What is the corect way of extracting the user's name from session?

Tags: php, mysql, object, session-variables

I have the following php classes :

```
class Threads {

private $url, $description, $OP, $timestamp, $score;

function __construct($url, $description, $OP, $timestamp, $score) {
    $this->url = $url;
    $this->description = $description;
    $timestamp->OP = $OP;
    $this->timestamp = $timestamp;
    $this->score = $score;
}

public function getUrl() {
    return $this->url;
}

public function getDescription() {
    return $this->description;
}

public function getOP() {
    return $this->OP;
}

public function getTimestamp() {
    return $this->timestamp;
}

public function getScore() {
    return $this->score;
}

public function setUrl($url) {
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function setDescription($description) {
    $this->description = $description;
}

public function setOP($OP) {
    $this->OP = $OP;
}

public function setTimestamp($timestamp) {
    $this->timestamp = $timestamp;
}

public function setScore($score) {
    $this->score = $score;
}

}
```

and

```
class ThreadsController {

private static $singleton = NULL;

public static function getInstance() {
    if (self::$singleton == NULL)
        self::$singleton = new self;
    return self::$singleton;
}

public function getYoutubeVideoId($url) {

    $pattern = '%^  # Match any youtube URL
    (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
    (?:www\.)?      # Optional www subdomain
    (?:             # Group host alternatives
      youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
    | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
      (?:           # Group path alternatives
        /embed/     # Either /embed/
      | /v/         # or /v/
      | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
      )             # End path alternatives.
    )               # End host alternatives.
    ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
    $%x';

    $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    if ($result != false) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return FALSE;
}

public function addThread($thread) {
    return mysql_query("INSERT INTO `threads` VALUES    (NULL,'{$thread->getUrl()}','{$thread->getDescription()}','{$thread->getOp()}','{$thread->getTimestamp()}','{$thread->getScore()}')");
}

}
```

I am calling them here , in an attempt to store the posted thread :

```
$url = $mc->getYoutubeVideoId($_POST['postUrl']);
$description = $_POST['postDescription'];
______________________________________________
$OP = serialize($_SESSION['user'] -> username);
______________________________________________
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d');
$score = 0;

$threadposting = $mc->addThread(new Threads($url, $description, $OP, $timestamp,   $score));
```

The problem is that in the mysql database , the field for $OP remains blank and I get an error : " Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object ".

Comment: $_SESSION does not have a key called 'user'. If you force that, you must force it to be an object with an attribute called username. I see nothing in your code that starts the session, sets a key called user, or a user object with an attribute called username. It looks like you copied and pasted code from someone else without caring about what the code was referencing.

Comment: In the full file , I do start the session with session_start();
And in the login file I set $_SESSION['user']= $oject

Comment: The line $OP = serialize($_SESSION['user'] -> username); will not throw the error you mentioned. It is an error that is thrown when you use something line $myobject->field = 'something'; and $myobject is actually not an object. It should give you the line number so you can tell us which line is throwing the error.

Comment: On line | $timestamp->OP = $OP; | in the Threads class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After someone pointed out I realized that the constructor for $OP was badly written :

' $timestamp->OP = $OP; ' , I've changed it to $this -> OP = $OP;

Answer (score 0):

to use session in PHP you first have to start the session:

```
session_start();
```

then you have to set the session variable:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $username;
```

and when you want to get the username in an oder PHP file you have to start the session again.

Comment: In the full file , I do start the session , and $_SESSION['user'] = $object , I store in my my $_SESSION['user'] a new User($username, $password, $email);

Comment: so $_SESSION['user'] is an array? @Tiberiu

Comment: $_SESSION['user'] = mysql_fetch_object(query);

Comment: How do you handle when the query returns null? Then, $_SESSION['user'] will not be an object.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['user']) returns : object(stdClass)#1 (4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["username"]=> string(7) "Tiberiu" ["password"]=> string(6) "genericpassword" ["email"]=> string(13) "asd@gmail.com" } . $_SESSION['user'] is not empty only when I try to use ['username'] is when I encounter the error